# Mac book pro 2020, after water spill, OS keep restarting with the following error

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, damage

Unfortunately my mac got water on it 48 hours ago...

When I connect the mac to the power after several tries it turns on(while doing weird sound like entering a movie or something). When it reaches the Desktop then I have a message notifying that the computer shut down due to a problem with the error below, and after 3-5 minutes it turns off again.

Worth to say, the touch bar does not working at all.

Can anyone shed some light regarding this error? is it something with the hardware or might be reformat the OS can help?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Water damage can‘t be fixed by reformatting a drive…

Comment: This isn't what I asked...

Comment: In that case "is it something with the hardware or might be reformat the OS can help?" is at least misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dfrd` is the *Dynamic Function Row Daemon*, i.e., the piece of software that talks to the Touch Bar. The fact that your panic signature indicates that `dfrd` has not sent an "I'm alive!" message in 3 full minutes coincides perfectly with the fact that your Touch Bar is nonfunctional.

As your troubles only started after you spilled conductive fluid on your machine, the probability is high that you shorted one or more traces that were critical to allowing the Touch Bar to operate properly and for its driver software to communicate with the hardware. macOS apparently considers the Touch Bar to be an essential system component and was, therefore, designed to intentionally halt further operation of the machine when this so-called “essential” component fails.

You can run **[Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)** to confirm the hardware damage and then bring your machine to an Apple Store for **hardware repair**.

Answer (score 1):

I had repeat Kernel Panic failure, every 3 minutes.

Began with a few drops here and there and the TouchBar LCD failed. The digitizer still functioned so by guessing I could still utilize functions.

A couple months went by and little did I know that the digitizer failed. This  was the final straw, triggering the watchdog timeout.

Backed everything up in 3 min increments and began repair.

Taking apart my A1990 Macbook Pro, replacing the touchbar took about 1.5 hours to complete.

No more failures. Reformatted the machine for a fresh start. Maybe this is one of the reasons apple killed off the touchbar?

Don't take to Apple. Replacement touchbars are incredibly cheap (less than 40 bucks) and you only need a few very cheap and accessible tools.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/325605)