# Monterey (12.2.1) - repeated kernel panics by watchdog

Tags: macos, big-sur, kernel-panic, monterey

My MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019) is experiencing repeated kernel panics with the message below:

> panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff01cf956ec): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from dfrd since load
>
> service: com.apple.dfrd, no successful checkins since load (180 seconds ago)

It usually occurs within 5 minutes after booting up. The mouse suddenly freezes for a few seconds, then the system shuts down. Restarting results in the same issue.

There are numerous discussions on the Apple fora, and most of the content is "I had the same problem" and the best solutions are "update macOS" and "remove any peripherals."

Unfortunately, none of the solutions seems to be work. I updated from Big Sur to Monterey and the issue continues.

Currently, my "solution" is to boot in Safe Mode, leave the laptop idle for like an hour, and then restart.

Comment: Are you using Photos or storing photos in iCloud? Do you have an external monitor connected? Do you have other peripherals connected? Take a look at [this site](https://softwaretested.com/mac/how-to-fix-crashes-from-userspace-watchdog-timeout/) and see if using some of the remedies fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! Yes, I was using Photos and external monitor. I have disabled and disconnected them now, and the issue remains. I tried some remedies in that site and got no luck. Perhaps I should consider wipe the OS. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Is it possible that you exposed an area of the MBP near the Touch Bar to liquid or other damage? See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430556/mac-book-pro-2020-after-water-spill-os-keep-restarting-with-the-following-erro/430557#430557