# Experiencing kernel panics and shutdowns on MacBook Pro 2019 A2159

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, kernel-panic, shutdown

My MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019) is experiencing repeated kernel panics with the message below:

```
 panic(cpu 0 caller 0xfffffff015ba96ec): userspace watchdog timeout: no successful checkins from dfrd in 180 seconds
```

I've read elsewhere that `dfrd` relates to the Touch Bar.

For background, I bought the chassis of a MacBook Pro 2019 13-inch which only had a tested screen, everything else was untested (including the Touch Bar). I then put in a functioning logic board and was able to get it to boot with the caveat of it shutting off every 180 seconds, or 3 minutes. During the time that it's on the Touch Bar doesn't function. There seems to be a dent near the Touch Bar and I suppose a drop in its past could have affected the functionality.

I thought it might be a software issue so I wiped the SSD only to realize that it cannot reinstall an OS due to it restarting every 3 minutes. This means I'm stuck without an OS until I can get this issue solved. Running diagnostics I get `APD000` meaning no detected hardware issues so I'm at a loss. I took apart the MacBook as well, examining the different parts but I didn't notice any damages. Running diagnostics doesn't reveal anything and spits out `APD000` indicating that there are no hardware issues (though I know it can sometimes miss things, i.e. now)

I read that others with the same problem replaced the top case (the keyboard, Touch Bar, and top assembly) through Apple and had their issue resolved.

I hope answers don't involve sending it to Apple as I doubt they'd repair my Frankensteined MacBook.

Answer (score 0):

> I hope answers don't involve sending it to apple as I doubt they'd
> repair my frankensteined macbook.

Unfortunately, that's exactly what it means. See my answer to [Mac book pro 2020, after water spill, OS keep restarting with the following error](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430556/mac-book-pro-2020-after-water-spill-os-keep-restarting-with-the-following-erro/430557#430557)

You may have luck with an Apple-authorized repair center.